# Confusion with $\lim_{x\to \infty} (e^x+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}$

Tags: limits

I have this limit:

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} (e^x+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}$$

At first I was stumped but then decided to use L'hospitals rule and logs so it turns to:

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\ln(e^x+x)}{x}$$

Then differentiating it twice turns to:

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{e^x}{e^x+1}$$

But then this means $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{e^x}{e^x+1}=1$, but I know from trying values on my calculator that it should be equal to $e$.

Am I wrong or am I getting mixed up with the L'Hospitals rule? Thank you!

Comment: The intuitive answer is immediate: $x$ is quite negligible in front of $e^x$ and the expression tends to $e$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

... just a silly mistake. If $\ln L=1$ , then what do you think $L$ should be equal to?

Comment: So can I just do $e^1$, is this how l’hospitals rule normally works?

Comment: Oh is it because I took logs first then I have to reverse it?

Comment: Yes, first convert into $\frac 0 0 $ or $\frac \infty \infty $ form,  then differentiate until you get a determinate form.

Comment: Yes, you have to take log both sides, and then reverse it. What did  you think initially!!!!

Comment: I was just confused why the limit was not $1$ but then I realised that I need to take the "exponential" of each side so remove the log so it leads to $e^1=e$.

Answer (score 5):

Why differentiate twice? After differentiating once you get$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^x+1}{e^x+x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1+e^{-x}}{1+\frac x{e^x}}=1$$and so, yes, your limit is equal to $e^1=e$.

---

Actually, you don't need L'Hopital's rule *at all*. Just note that$$e^x<e^x+x<2e^x$$and that therefore$$e<(e^x+x)^{\frac1x}<2^{\frac1x}e$$and so, by the squeeze theorem, your limit is $e$.

Answer (score 1):

You can also factor $e^x$ out like this:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} e \left(1+x e^{-x}\right)^{1/x}\sim \lim_{x\to\infty} e\left(1+e^{-x}\right)= e$$

Comment: You should justify this equivalence, shouldn't you ?

Answer (score 0):

L'Hopital is really unnecessary in this case, just observe that $e^x$ dominates on $x$, therefore a good idea is to factor it out

$$( x + e^x)^{1/x}=( e^x)^{1/x}\left( \frac x { e^x}+1\right)^{1/x} \to e\cdot 1=e$$

since $1^0$ is not an indeterminate form.